# Wind burst turns on computer from sleep

Tags: power-supply, sleep, surge-protection

From time to time I manage to have my computer at sleep mode while I make some wind blow onto the computer. Like when shaking out the blanket or closing the door rashly. This computer configuration was always sensitive to wakes. I bought surge protector and disabled all USB wakes long time ago already.

I have 2 bets:

- Something in the supply
- Something in case power board.

While supply is at case bottom, blast likely comes there and affects some component.
What electro-mechanics could be behind this?

[image]

Comment: Is it a high-humidity environment? This sounds like static or ESD. Or, there's a loose cable (check the on/off switch header) which moves slightly when something moves enough in the environment to move it.

Comment: Is there an active camera or "person sensor"?

Comment: Is it perhaps sensitivity to sounds ?

Comment: Most likely cause would be a mouse that wakes the PC when moved and the wind moves the mouse a bit

Comment: As @YisroelTech states, likely the mouse detects movement. Unplug it and test if the computer stays asleep.

Comment: @YisroelTech: No, definitely not. I tried.

Comment: @JiminyCricket, I have webcamera but since all USB devices are prohibited to wake up, camera is not active. No way to cope with blow.

Comment: @harrymc, no, no. No sound sensitivity at all. Just sudden wind.

Comment: @spikey_richiem, never did any measurement, but it is normal flat, temperate climate. No extra humidity to worry about. I guess for ESD. I will: check for loose parts later and provide info about it.

Comment: I meant one connected as part of the monitor, or ir sensor or ultrasonic detector (camera focusing)?

Comment: "since all USB devices are prohibited to wake up" but maybe it's actually not properly prohibited? Did you try actually disconnecting them all and see if it's still happening?

Comment: @YisroelTech, I did try few times mouse movement and other wakeup tricks but USB devices showed to not be source of wakeups. I said this configuration was always sensitive. Imagine I turned on table lamp and computer went on.

Comment: @JiminyCricket, no, nothing like these.

Comment: @spikey_richie, I tried some movement with power cord and touching power switch on supply but this seems stable.

Comment: Maybe one more clue. While no mouse (or keboard, …) is capable of waking up PC, one mouse for unknown reason preserved this ability only on button click. This is, I guess, due not honring standards of ACPI Sleep States (S0 - S5). So maybe pulse is not invoked at supply but rather at USB/+motherboard?